# Django Admin Page missing CSS

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271731/djangos-admin-pages-are-missing-their-typical-formatting-style-have-i-set-it-up) and recommendation from Django Projects [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/?from=olddocs#id3) but still can't get this to work. My Django Admin pages are not displaying the CSS at all.

[image]

This is my current configuration.

**settings.py**

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'
```

**httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/django/sgel
    ServerName ec2-***-**-***-***.ap-**********-1.compute.amazonaws.com
    ErrorLog /home/django/sgel/logs/apache_error.log
    CustomLog /home/django/sgel/logs/apache_access.log combined
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/sgel/apache/django.wsgi

    <Directory /home/django/sgel/media>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/django/sgel/apache>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn

    Alias /media/ /home/django/sgel/media/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName sgel.com
   Redirect permanent / http://www.sgel.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

In addition, I also ran the following to create (I think) the symbolic link
`ln -s /home/djangotest/sgel/media/admin/ /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/`

**UPDATE**

In my httpd.conf file,

```
User django
Group django
```

When I run ls -l in my `/media` directory

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  4 11:03 admin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr  8 09:02 test.txt
```

Should that root user be django instead?

**UPDATE 2**
When I enter `ls -la` in my `/media/admin` folder

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 13 03:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr  8 09:02 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   60 Apr 13 03:33 media -> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
```

The thing is, when I navigate to `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/`, the folder was empty. So I copied the CSS, IMG and JS folders from my Django installation into `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/` and it still didn't work

Comment: To answer your question about the ownership of the subdirectories under `/media`: no, the file permissions don't restrict other users from having read access to those files (see the rx bits on group and others access), so the file permissions are not an issue.

Comment: @photoionized Ah thanks. Still getting my feet wet in linux!

Comment: What is the error page you get when you go to /media/admin/css/base.css?

Comment: When I goto `http://www.sgel.com/media/admin/css/base.css`, I get `Oops this link appears to be broken`

Comment: Looks like the symbolic link still isn't set up right. Is it possible you mucked up the location `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/` with your original attempt to make a symlink?

Comment: I don't know? How do I check and start from scratch? I've been following Daniel Roseman's solution after my attempt

Comment: Added a new answer, please try it and update the results here... Hope it helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to correcting the symbolic link as Daniel Roseman suggested, you'll need to make sure that the user that is running Apache has read access to the admin media.

- If you do `ls -l` in your media directory, do you see the symbolic link?
- If you `cd admin` from your media directory, does it work? If you then run `ls` can you see the admin media?
- Does the user that runs Apache have read access to the admin media?

If all those things work, then please update your question with your current configuration and results of those commands and we'll take another look.

**Response to Update**: Ok, the permissions look ok. It looks like you've got the directory structure in your media directory a little bit wrong.

The fact that `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/` was empty is disturbing, too. Once you solve the immediate problem you may want to look into reinstall django in the expected place.

Anyways, here's how the structure should look:

```
$ cd media
$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 13 03:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr  8 09:02 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   60 Apr 13 03:33 admin -> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9 Apr  8 09:02 test.txt
```

That is, inside of the `media/` directory their should be a link called `admin` directly to the `/admin/media` directory of your django installation.

To fix what you've got, inside of the `media/admin/` directory run:

```
rm media
cd ..
rmdir admin
```

and then re-create the symlink as suggested in Daniel Roseman's answer.

Comment: @nai from your update it looks like your admin folder is media/admin/media but your settings.py file says `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'`. if you Follow What Sean has said it will work. Otherwise change your settings.py to `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/media/'`.

Comment: @James @Sean Wallace - I think I finally understand what's going on now. I think what happened was I somehow created a media folder in my `/media/admin` which led to the sym link being created in `/media/admin/media` which didn't match the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` setting. It's actually quite a straight forward problem afterall. Thanks for your help guys esp. your comment James. It made everything click in my understanding.

Comment: strange, I accepted your answer before the bounty was over. I'm not sure why you only received half.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out! No worries on the bounty thing.

Answer (score 7):

There's a couple of problems here, both to do with your symbolic link.

Firstly, the source and target needed to be the other way round (I always get that wrong myself).

Secondly, you have used a completely different path to the one you've specified in your Apache conf - `djangotest/sgelections` vs `django/sgel`.

Do it like this:

```
cd /home/django/sgel/media/
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/ admin
```

Comment: My bad, type on my part. I tried the new sym link and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ampersandre yeah, I take back what I said. was being myopic in my comment.

Answer (score 6):

The easy solution is to change a line in your wsgi.py file

```
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

becomes

```
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    from dj_static import Cling

    application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Easiest way to have the Admin CSS show properly. Cheers

Comment: Very neat quick solution. Worked for me (Python 3.4, Django 1.8 running on Ubuntu 14.10 @ DigitalOcean).

Answer (score 5):

Another method I just found, and it looks like a properly supported method.

Make sure you have the staticfiles module in your settings. Also configure the STATIC_ROOT option.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#module-django.contrib.staticfiles

Create your /static/ folder and set permissions.

Configure apache with a /static/ alias.

```
alias /static <path to project root>/static/
<Directory "<path to project root>/static/">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

then from your project folder run

```
sudo python manage.py collectstatic [-n to do a dry run]
```

All this looks like it does is copy the admin static files to your projects folder for web serving.

Comment: I agree.  This seems to be the "proper" way to make these static files available.

Answer (score 3):

So the first thing you want to do is change directory to your static folder and add a symlink.

I did this with a virtual environment so I use

```
ln -s ~/virtualenv/my-virtualenv/lib/python2.x/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin admin
```

The next step is to edit your httpd.conf

> Alias /static/admin/ ~/mysite/static/admin/

Restart your apache server and voila!

Answer (score 2):

In Firebug, use the Net tab and see the requests being made by your browser for the css files. see the response for your requests there itself. I think you will find the problem there.
I recently had the same problem. The problem was when my browser requests for the css files, the response contained the contents of my project's login html page. I don't remember now that how i solved my problem. I will try to recollect and post the solution here.
Let me know if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but none of this helped really. Turned out my version of grappelli was outdated. (https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli) I uninstalled it and then re-installed with a newer version. 
        `pip install django-grappelli==2.4.4`
If you are using an admin skin like me, you might consider updating it.

Answer (score 1):

can you run

```
python
>>> import django
>>> print django.__file__
```

the other question - does your normal media placed into the /home/django/sgel/media/ work (i.e. served by Apache as expected?)

Comment: >>> import django
>>> print django.__file__
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc
>>> 

I don't serve any media files on my site at the moment...

Comment: try putting some test.txt file into your media folder and test opening www.sgel.com/test.txt. if not opened, the problem is with your Apache config in general, not in admin-cpecific media

Comment: good news - this means apache serves static properly. is it possible when you created a symlink you boke django's admin media dir?

try the following: reinstall django; cd /home/django/sgel/media/; check django location as explained above; run ln -s DJANGO_LOCATION/contrib/admin/media admin

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

to your

```
<Directory /home/django/sgel/media>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

so that you end up with

```
<Directory /home/django/sgel/media>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I've added `Options FollowSymLinks` and re-started Apache. Still no joy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help but in my config file I have:

```
    Alias /adminmedia/ /var/lib/python-support/python2.6/django/contrib/admin/media/   

    <Directory "/var/lib/python-support/python2.6/django/contrib/admin/media"> 
            AllowOverride None                                                 
            Options FollowSymLinks                                             
            Order allow,deny                                                   
            Allow from all                                                     
    </Directory>
```

It works but I have my server set up for development/testing only.

Answer (score 1):

i used to have the same problem, i solved it by using the FireFox plugin firebug, which tells you where is your site looking for the media files, also how did you check the contents of the admin/media folder to see if they were empty ?

Comment: I just navigated to the folder?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been solved but I think it's worthy to share my solution.

I simply added the alias in apache and it worked so far.

```
    Alias /static/admin/ /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
    Alias admin/media/ /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
```

Comment: Perfect. In my case it was `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/admin/media`. One should `cd /usr/lib` and `ls -a -R | grep -i media` to see what the directory is under one's operating system and python version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the value for

MEDIA_ROOT 
MEDIA_URL 
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX

correctly?

I mean that the MEDIA_ROOT url and ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFX should have a different value. Please check these values in your settings.py and try again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem while running the Bitnami Django Stack on Win32  (builtin development server)

I solved the issue by finding the missing CSS folders in the installation and changing settings.py.

```
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'C:/Program Files/BitNami DjangoStack/apps/django/django/contrib',
)
```

This will help you get started developing... It's not optimal. Don't forget the trailing comma :)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing helps, add the following to urls.py

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { <br/>
            'document_root': '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/', <br/>
           'show_indexes' : True, <br/>
        }), <br/>
```

This is independent of apache or nginx

Answer (score 0):

when we talked about django, we should know which edition we run on. "ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX" is used in django before edition of 1.4, see

```
The included administration app django.contrib.admin has for a long time 
shipped with a default set of static files such as JavaScript, images and 
stylesheets. Django 1.3 added a new contrib app django.contrib.staticfiles 
to handle such files in a generic way and defined conventions for static 
files included in apps.
Starting in Django 1.4, the admin's static files also follow this convention, 
to make the files easier to deploy. In previous versions of Django, it was 
also common to define an ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX setting to point to the URL where 
the admin's static files live on a Web server. This setting has now been deprecated 
and replaced by the more general setting STATIC_URL. Django will now expect to 
find the admin static files under the URL <STATIC_URL>/admin/.
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/. 
I am using django 1.4, and still confusing about this.

Comment: I find it, and it works. For django 1.4 with apache, links as follow would be helped.[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files) , [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967849/django-1-4-admin-static-files-without-staticfiles-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967849/django-1-4-admin-static-files-without-staticfiles-app)

Comment: First, I set `STATICFILES_DIRS` as `"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/"`. and set `STATIC_ROOT` as `os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, '../static')` and Second I use `collectstatic' to collect static file from 'STATICFILES_DIRS` to `STATIC_ROOT`. Third ,set `STATIC_URL` as `/tdjproj/static/`. Forth, Alias STATIC_URL to STATIC_ROOT(eg. `Alias /tdjproj/static/ /var/www/vhost1/tdjproj/static/`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `virtualenvwrapper` like me, then this is how you can find your admin media files and fix it:

```
workon <project_name>
export DJANGO_BASEFILE=`python -c 'import django; print django.__file__'`
export DJANGO_BASEDIR=$(dirname ${DJANGO_BASEFILE})
ln -s $DJANGO_BASEDIR/contrib/admin/media <project_dir>/media/admin
```

Replace the `<project_name>` to your virtualenvwrapper environment name and `project_dir` to your working directory. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this issue occured after setting up the nginx on Ubuntu server. On analyzing the file structure, I found that admin folder was missing from the staticfile directory (the location where django looks for static files to add to `STATIC_ROOT`). So, I copied the admin folder (inside static directory) to the server's static folder.
Then run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

And now, django collects the 130 files required for admin page styling.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to Adam's Solution,

first you need to install dj-static in cpanel. So add dj-static==0.0.6 in requirements.txt then install

```
dj-static==0.0.6
```

and then edit the project wsgi.py file:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

then restart the cpanel. Hope Admin will have a Proper Look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

a simple answer for this problem is moving admin and static folder to public_html

I had this problem and it worked
try it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I am Ansh Sharma. I also faced this same issue, and it was just too scary. Here I have something which can solve the problem. Go to Your setting file and make

```
DEBUG = TRUE
```

I hope this solves your issue
Happy Coding.
Ansh Sharma

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: why we run website with debug true

Comment: Just to be clear, you should not enable ```DEBUG = True``` when in production.