# Permissions error when accessing Django admin page served by Apache

Tags: django, apache, django-admin, apache2

I am new to Django development and this site has been invaluable so far and I'm impressed with how much I've learned.  That being said, I am running into a problem and I've been crawling through the related posts on this site yet can't seem to find anything that solves my issue.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271731/djangos-admin-pages-are-missing-their-typical-formatting-style-have-i-set-it-u?lq=1) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537268/django-admin-page-missing-css) [what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967849/django-1-4-admin-static-files-without-staticfiles-app?lq=1) [I've](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565935/django-staticfiles-app-help) [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985342/apache-403-while-serving-django-static-files) [but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500598/apache-not-serving-django-admin-static-files) [no](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/deployment/) [luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824359/django-static-files).

So I am hoping that one of you might be able to take a look at what I'm doing and point me in the right direction.  I am trying to get my Apache web server to serve up the CSS files for Django's admin page.  But, when visiting: `http://localhost/admin/`, I get the error: `Forbidden.  You don't have permission to access /admin/ on this server.`

The CSS/JS for my site is located in `mysite/static` and the CSS/JS for the admin page is located in the Django installation folder, `Django-1.5/django/contrib/admin/static/admin`. Here are the relevant bits in my `settings.py` file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/production_static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS = (
    "/home/me/Django-1.5/django/contrib/admin/static/admin",
    "/home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/static",
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',

)
```

I've run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command which pulls all the necessary static files from my two directory locations and places them in a folder called `production_static` in my project folder.

Here is the `production_static` folder layout:

```
$ cd production_static
$ ls
admin css images img js
```

The `admin` folder contains all the static files needed for the admin page to display.  But for some reason, the `css` folder contains both my site's CSS as well as the admin CSS.  Same with the `js` folder.  The `images` folder is my site's images and the `img` folder is the admin site's images.  I don't know why the `collectstatic` command is making two copies of the admin's static files.

Here is Apache's `httpd.conf` file:

```
AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/production_static/css/$1
AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/production_static/admin/css/$1

Alias /media/ /home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/media/
Alias /static/ /home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/production_static/
Alias /admin/ /home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/production_static/admin/

<Directory /home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/production_static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite    

<Directory /home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I am making sure that I restart the Apache server every time I make changes to the `httpd.conf` file.

And here is my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.homepage_view'),
    # other url-view mappings here
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My homepage and other pages load fine.  The CSS and JS are all wonderful.  It's just when I try to access `http://localhost/admin/` do I get a permissions error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of this alias:

```
Alias /admin/ /home/me/Desktop/djcode/mysite/production_static/admin/
```

Comment: Wow....that was it.  Thanks so much!  Can you explain why that line was causing me problems?

Comment: Because it is not supposed to be there. You're already assigning an alias to `static`. And `admin` is just a subfolder to `static`.

Comment: It is also recommended that you serve your static and media files using another webserver like nginx.

Comment: why nginx over Apache?

Comment: It's recommended not to serve both django and static files with Apache.