# How to link to CSS stylesheet up (in folder location)

Tags: css, django

I have always been a little confused about the correct place for a static folder for my Django project. Should one be located at the project level? or at the application level? Increasingly [through looking at tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Bwl5CYa5Uc) it seems that most suggest keeping a static folder at the project level.

My problem is that I can't seem to correctly link to a bootstrap Stylesheet that is in another directory at the project level.

I am able to link to the CSS files in my survey application at **A** using

```
<link href = "/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
```

However none of the below will link to **B**

```
<link href = "../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<link href = "../../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<link href = "../../../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
```

What is the correct way of linking to the `bootstrap.min.css`stylesheet at **B** below?

I don't want to start using full file paths as that will require changes on deployment and additional upkeep

Below is my project structure.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537268/django-admin-page-missing-css

Comment: Where is your url handler, like app.yaml? Does the static directory 'B' need to be outside the project?  Can you post `__init__.py` in `survey`?

Comment: No, the static directory B does not need to be outside the application (It is inside the project) But as I mentioned in my question these seems to be the standard so I want to use the same. My __init__.py file is blank