# Django Admin Page missing CSS in IIS

Tags: python, iis, python-3.4, django-1.8

I am getting a similar error to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537268/django-admin-page-missing-css), but it only happens when I go to the website I set up in IIS 2012R2.

I am following this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/#start-the-development-server) to start a web app, and I used this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXbfHtAvubc) to set up Django with IIS. I successfully set up the Django using IIS, but I a missing the CSS on the admin page.

Note that the admin page displays the CSS items if I run the page using runserver command.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But if I run it through http://127.0.0.1:8003/admin/ in IE (setup through IIS), I get the picture shown below. I tried this in Chrome, and it gave me same results.

Do I need configure my wfastcgi.py file to show CSS? In the video tutorial, the author talks about a static folder in IIS for JPEGS, Javascript...do I need to configure this?

[image]

I am using Django 1.8.4 and Python 3.4.

This is my current configuration:

**settings.py**

```
    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '&y%=6k2y4z5_ut3z#&1l2lh3v12#zyxws)o&5^fj^ik^79pys('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin', #admin site
    'django.contrib.auth', #authentication system
    'django.contrib.contenttypes', #framework for content types
    'django.contrib.sessions', #ssession framework
    'django.contrib.messages', #messaging framework
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', #framework for managing static files
    'polls',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'FirstSite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'FirstSite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),]
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "FirstSite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**manage.py**

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "FirstSite.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find an answer with the help of a colleague.

The answer is highlighted here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312590/how-to-fetch-static-css-files-with-django-on-iis)

If you follow the above solution, please keep in mind the following (which is what the above person mentioned):

- The Static folder where you keep all the CSS, jpegs, etc files is not the same as the static folder they are referring to in the solution
- Make sure you run the command collectstatic to compile all the static files from the STATIC_URL folder to the STATIC_ROOT folder
- When you run the collectstatic it will compile the Admin static files as well

Answer (score 2):

You should set your STATICFILES_DIRS settings in settings.py, to map to your static folder, where CSS, JS and images are stored.

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://www.example.com/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'static'),
)
```

Also if you run 'manage.py collectstatic' you should define

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/path/to/static/destination/folder/"
```

This is the best way to serve static files.

Reference for STATIC settings: [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#settings-staticfiles)

Comment: Thank you for your solution, the CSS is now showing. I did not end up needing STATICFILES_DIRS, I just mapped the static files to STATIC_ROOT after the 'manage.py collecstatic. Do you think I need to use the STATICFILES_DIRS?