# Serve static files with IIS and Django

Tags: python, django, iis, static, wfastcgi

I'm getting an error when trying to serve **static** file on IIS using FastCGI with **Django==2.2.5** and **python==3.7.4**
my ***settings.py***

static code

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'static')
```

I'm using [wfastcgi](https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/) version 3.0.0 and my server is **windows server 2012 datacenter R2**.
I tried all solution here [Django Admin Page missing CSS in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593634/django-admin-page-missing-css-in-iis) and here [How to fetch static CSS files with django on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312590/how-to-fetch-static-css-files-with-django-on-iis/32340030) and watched some tutorial on youtube but still stuck with that.

The error when it shows when I'm trying to access the admin page

> GET http://xxxxxx/static/admin/css/base.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not
>   Found)

Comment: When you connect your django project with web servers, you should handle static files with web servers in most cases

Comment: I don't get your point, how I can do that? any code or example?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to figure what your environment situation may be, but you may me missing a Virtual link to your static directory in IIS. Also, you will need a `web.config` in your static directory. Your project will require a total of two `web.config` files.

Here is an example of what your static directory should look like https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/webproject/tree/master/static

You can review that project and follow along in the tutorial [Deploy Django on Windows using Microsoft IIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APCQ15YqqQ0&feature=youtu.be)