# Django 1.6 Admin page CSS not working with Bluehost

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, bluehost, django-1.6

I am trying to upload my Django App to Bluehost and for some reason none of the CSS is working on the admin page, I have been touring the web for hours looking for solutions but I haven't found any specifically tailored to Bluehost or Django 1.6. This Question was the closest thing to what I need but it still isn't working. [Django's admin is missing css, images, etc - unable to properly set up static files on shared host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883036/djangos-admin-is-missing-css-images-etc-unable-to-properly-set-up-static-fi) All of my static files are now in /public_html/static/, it worked for that person so I am curious to know what I am doing wrong.

Here is the pertinent code

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/mySite/Django/WebApp/quiz'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/mySite/public_html/QuizApp/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

After I edited settings.py I did run collectstatic. Also I feel like this may be important as well.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tempaltes')]
```

and the .htaccess file because Bluehost doesn't allow you to access the httpd.conf file

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ QuizApp.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you all need anything else let me know. This is my first experience with web development, python, and CSS in general so please be as detailed as possible I literally know nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copied and pasted your code directly from your files, then the first thing you might try is correcting the typo in your template_dirs assignment.

You have:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tempaltes')]
```

It should be:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

Also, you might check whether your STATIC_ROOT is set accurately.

It should be:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/<user>/public_html/subdirectory/static/'
```

Your subdirectory looks fine (QuizApp), but it looks like you have the name of your project site 'mySite' where your username should be. With bluehost you want your static_root to be /home/username/...

UPDATED ANSWER:

Your STATIC_ROOT is the full-path to the directory where your static files will be moved to and stored (when you run collectstatic). Your STATIC_URL is the url your app will refer to when sourcing static files. With bluehost, anything in a file path after '/public_html/' is accessible by the web. This means any folder after '/public_html/' can/must show up in a url (after your domain name) pointing to any file in that folder.

In this case your STATIC_ROOT is '/home/mySite/public_html/QuizApp/static/' 
but your STATIC_URL is '/static/', so it looks like your url is pointing to the wrong place.

So, if for example, your domain name is "coolsite.com", then your static files are being stored in 'www.coolsite.com/QuizApp/static/' but the url you're pointing to is just 'www.coolsite.com/static/'. So try changing your STATIC_URL to '/QuizApp/static/' and then run 'python manage.py collectstatic' again.

Comment: I tried all of that and it still doesn't work :/ I even went to the admin css files directly and hard coded all the file paths to the static folder in public_html, do you think it would be better if I switched to django 1.4?

Comment: No, django 1.6 is preferable, and I just recently used it in a bluehost account myself, so I wouldn't suggest throwing in the towel yet. :) -I'll edit my answer above with an additional suggestion.