# Saleor Django Apache mod_wsgi will not serve /static/admin/

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am running the saleor django app under a virtualenv with apache as a non-privileged user.

Actually getting everything going was fairly straightforward, but one bit is confusing me.

The /static/admin/ portion of the site is not being served.

I have looked at the [deployment docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files) and [other advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271731/djangos-admin-pages-are-missing-their-typical-formatting-style-have-i-set-it-u) but have found nothing that helps, so far.

My /static/ directory is being served just fine. I'm sure it's something very obvious to the non-django-noob, but that's what I am. I'm not certain that it's copacetic to alias a sub-directory in another aliased directory. I'd rather not resort to symlinks.

```
# dev-site.conf

WSGIPythonPath/home/admin/project/saleor:/home/admin/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin email@example.com
        DocumentRoot "/home/admin/project"

        WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/home/admin/project/saleor:/home/admin/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup example.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/admin/project/saleor/wsgi.py

        Alias /media/ /home/admin/project/media/
        <Directory /home/admin/project/media/>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /favicon.ico /home/admin/project/saleor/static/images/favicon.ico
        Alias /robots.txt /home/admin/project/saleor/static/robots.txt
        Alias /static/ /home/admin/project/saleor/static/
        <Directory /home/admin/project/saleor/static/>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /static/admin/ /home/admin/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/
        <Directory /home/admin/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/admin/project>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I include my saleor/wsgi.py for smarts.

```
# wsgi.py

python

import os
import sys
import site

site.addsitedir("/home/admin/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
os.environ.setdefault("SECRET_KEY", "br549")
os.environ.setdefault("MYSQL_DB_URL", "mysql://dbuser:doublesecret@dbuser-dev.example.com:3306/saleor")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "saleor.settings")

project = "/home/admin/project/saleor"
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
sys.path.append(workspace)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: My code fences seem to be hosing the markdown formatter. Advice on that will be taken, too. :-D

Comment: Thanks. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't attempt to get Apache to serve directly from the static directory of either your own apps or the admin app. Instead, follow the documentation and use the `collectstatic` command to collect the static files for all apps in one place and serve from there.

Comment: I read that portion of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files), too. Unfortunately, I could not get it to work. I'm missing something.

Comment: [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) is the bit of the docs you should be following. If it's not working, post any error, and the relevant parts of your settings.py.

Comment: I think I finally have my head around what is *supposed* to happen. I didn't realize one had to do "django-admin collectstatic" (which is refusing to see my DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=saleor.static, so I'm guessing there is some extra gymkhana I'm going to have to go through to make that work in a virtual env) to copy everything somewhere magical for django to use. I'm going to have to let this rest before I impress my co-workers with my command of profanity.

Comment: Apparently I'm having troubles running collectstatic because I don't have django globally installed and it can't find my DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE setting without doing a relative import. 

This seems like a hell of a lot of precursors just to set a path.

Comment: No, you don't need (and shouldn't have) Django installed globally. Use `./manage.py collectstatic` from inside your project.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that I need to be running manage.py, rather than django-admin like the docs describe. I am not hip to this platforms shibboleths yet.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the documentation on [serving the admin files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files) or [django-admin collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic).

The documentation for serving the admin files indicated that if one has "django.contrib.staticfiles" enabled in the INSTALLED_APPS portion of settings.py, then it is recommended the STATICFILES_DIRS list in settings.py shall contain the paths to the "static" directory (django/contrib/admin/static/admin) provided by django for it's development server.

One is told to use the collectstatic management command which will physically copy the files to a "static" directory in what you will configure as ServerRoot in your sitename.conf file for apache to serve.

My problem was pretty much a noob error. I followed the instructions without knowing that there is some sort of received wisdom about what actually is used to run the "collectstatic" command.

Rather than

```
django-admin collecstatic
```

one needs to (in my case, ymmv)

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

When invoking collectstatic with django-admin, I got the maddening error:

```
ImportError: No module named saleor.settings
```

which was very confusing to me, as I had set that enivronment variable in both my .env file and in my wsgi.py file. I figured this might be some sort of quirk with virtualenv.  Setting this variable on the command line resulted in:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Which led me down a very disgusting rabbit-hole vis. my virtualenv setup and every config file I had ever edited. They were fine, fortunately. The actual invocation was with

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /home/admin/project/static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:
```

Which then proceeds to magically copy what I need (I hope!) into my project/static directory.

My noob mistake was not reading [django-admin and manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/) first, thus discovering that the convenience script has a convenience script. *RIMSHOT*

Another bit of confusion (for me, anyway) is the assertion that one should not serve static files from the "app" or the "admin app". A simpler way for me to think about it is: "one must run a script that appears either wrap or replicate rsync, thus copying static files from myapp/static and ~/project/venv/lib/python2.7/contrib/admin so that apache will not be able to play silly buggers with important files". This does NOT mean that one does not put a path to /static/ in the sitename.conf file. There is no magic here, just copying static files.

Therefore:

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/admin/project/saleor:/home/admin/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin email@example.com
        DocumentRoot "/home/admin/project"

        Alias /media/ /home/admin/project/media/
        <Directory /home/admin/project/media/>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /static/ /home/admin/project/static/
        <Directory /home/admin/project/static/>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/home/admin/project/saleor:/home/admin/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup example.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/admin/project/saleor/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/admin/project>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I now have static files being served from ~/project/static/ directory!

/me wipes away sweat.

Thanks Daniel!